# How do I set a system property from the admin console in Glassfish 3?

Tags: java, glassfish, glassfish-3

I found [this this](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18930_01/html/821-2416/ghcjc.html) article on how to do it on the command line, but I'd like to set it from the admin console (the GUI) or modifying the domain.xml.  In glassfish v2, this was as simple as modifying the domain.xml and adding a `<jvm-options>`.  But, I did the same thing in glassfish v3, and my war doesn't seem to have access to this property.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be changed by going to

```
server -> properties
```

Then adding a system property by pressing the "Add Property" button.

Comment: Where exactly is the difference to setting the System Property as JVM Option with `-Dproperty=value`? There is a broken link to Sun Docs on https://blogs.oracle.com/hyau/entry/how_to_set_jvm_option with the details, but it is not working anymore: http://docs.sun.com/app/docs/doc/819-2557/6n4rbnpba?a=view#abhau

Answer (score 9):

It should be as easy as you described it. If you want to go "domain.xml-way" you have to make sure the additional `<jvm-options>` is inside of the existing `<java-config>` like this:

```
  <java-config>
    <jvm-options>-XX:NewRatio=2</jvm-options>
  </java-config>
```

You must restart the server to make it work. 
Alternativly you can set it up in the Glassfish admin GUI (`http://localhost:4848`). 
Navigate to `Configurations` -> `server-config` -> `JVM Settings` -> `JVM Options` and add your new option.

[image: glassfish admin gui]